# Obtener las rutas de Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Tengo una base de datos con firebase necesito obtener todas las direcciones con una variable de un array o list si es posible de  `-LkRPmSuYvWEqrxkQ_aP`(Las 3 direcciones que están marcada con rojo) para luego acceder a ellas y mostrar el valor que estan dentro de ellas al usuario utilizo `push` para crearlas que crea los nombres aleatorio y necesito obtener todos los nombres que desconozco para mostrar todo esos datos al usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   Button btnSubir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSubir = findViewById(R.id.btnSubirFoto);

    //Crea la instancia
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    //Crea la referencia y el nombre de la base de datos
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.TUTORIAL_REFERENCE);



    //Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos: " + valor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //toast1.show();
    //Para cambiar el valor
   // myRef.setValue(4);

    ///////////BUTON////////////
    btnSubir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego");


            myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("nombre").setValue("Diego");
            myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("numero").setValue("+5687484");
            myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("foto").setValue("url");
            myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("biografia").setValue("Me gusta el futbol");
            myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("chats").child("Marcos");
            myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("chats").child("Marcos").child("mensajes").push().setValue("hola");




        }
    });
    ///////////BUTON///////////




}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los datos podes hacer lo siguiente

```
 myRef.child("usuario").child("Diego").child("chats").child("Marcos").child("mensajes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        final List<String> listaMensajes = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        listaMensajes.add(snapshot.getValue(String.class)); // Agrega todos los mensajes a la lista
        //list.add(snapshot.getKey()); //Agrega todos los keys a la lista, por ej -LkRPmSuYvWEqrxkQ_aP

        }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      Log.e("Error solicitando los datos:",databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

De esta forma guardas todos los nombres solicitados de mensajes en la lista.

Ahora, si necesitas buscar por cada usuario, cambias el nombre Marcos al que necesites, si es dinamico, lo podes hacer por codigo.

PD: dentro del for te comenté la linea para añadir las pushkey a la lista, si necesitas solo los mensajes , la primer lista como esta te va a devolver los mensajes de todas las keys, si necesitas solo los id, la segunda linea comentada te va a devolver los id de todos los menasjes.

Comment: agradecido de su respuesta que me soluciono  tengo una pequeña confusión ¿Porque la variable de listaMensajes es declarado como 'final' y la variable list no esta declarada con un cambio ligero el código funciona perfectamente

Comment: declaras final por que lo estas accediendo adentro de onDataChange y es una variable que no es mutable (no cambia), si probas reasignar la variable no te va a dejar. Basicamente es para prevenir que mientras se estan trayendo los elementos a la lista, la puedas modificar externamente antes que la llamada asyncrona termine